# Django ProgrammingError column does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

I've recently migrated to postgresql, I was not sure about the cause of the problem but column does not exist error is  showing up.

ProgrammingError at /admin/mtsauth/authorms/
column mtsauth_authorms.nihgrants does not exist
LINE 1: ..."secfirstname", "mtsauth_authorms"."seclastname", "mtsauth_a...

this is migrations file

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='AuthorMS',
            fields=[
                ('firstname', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
                ('lastname', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
                ('ArticleId', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, `enter code here`serialize=False)),
                ('secfirstname', models.CharField(blank=True, default='None', max_length=120)),
                ('seclastname', models.CharField(blank=True, default='None', max_length=120)),
                ('nihgrants', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('country', models.CharField(choices=[('INDIA', 'INDIA'), ('US', 'USA'), ('UK', 'UK'), ('RUSSIA', 'RUSSIA')], max_length=50)),
                ('seccountry', models.CharField(blank=True, choices=[('INDIA', 'INDIA'), ('US', 'USA'), ('UK', 'UK'), ('RUSSIA', 'RUSSIA')], default='None', max_length=50)),
                ('affliation', models.CharField(default='None', max_length=100)),
                ('secAffliation', models.CharField(blank=True, default='None', max_length=100)),
                ('code', models.IntegerField(default=101, max_length=10000)),
            ],
        ),
```

Comment: What did you run at first place after  creating database in postgres?

Comment: Firstly I've deleted all .pyc files and migrations files and I've run  this command : python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: Have you tried : python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>

Comment: Yes I've tried it, it worked. But when i was opening the admin panel and clicking the above model link to add data, the error is showing up then.

Comment: After makemigrations, you need to run migrate as well. ``` python manage.py migrate <app_name>```

Comment: Tried it , but its not working , anyways thanks Sijan

Comment: Why did you delete your migration files? What made you think that was the correct thing to do?

Comment: validationerror for datefield came when i did not delete my .pyc and migration files, and one of stackoverflow answers suggested to delete these files and run makemigrations command

Comment: Please inspect your database to confirm that the field exists. Are you using custom database routing or schema's (ie. Django Tenant Schemas?)

Comment: im not using any tenant schema, working with general one. thanks digaph

Answer (score 0):

Your changes are not fully reflected in the database.  This could be because you have not migrated to the database.  Be sure you provide value for non-nullable fields to your model by giving them a default value.  You can check the status of a migration by running the following command:

```
python manage.py showmigrations <your_app_name>
```

This will show the list of migrations.  The one without the X to the left of migration is the one you have missed to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Comment all your `urls.py` lines. Including all imports. Except:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

admin = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In terminal run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Solved.