# Django error app engine deploy in standard env

Tags: python, django, postgresql, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a django app on google app engine using postgress, and i´m running out of ideas about what could be causing this error.

Everithing up perfect, but when i'm going to authenticate into django-admin, it throws me this error.

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/login/

relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://don-numero.uc.r.appspot.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
                                                             ^
Exception Location: /env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 86
Python Executable:  /env/bin/python3.7
Python Version: 3.7.7
Python Path:    
['/srv',
 '/env/bin',
 '/opt/python3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Already check the db access, setting file, migrations, and everything is setup correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The "does not exist" ProgrammingError indicates that the your expectations and the database's reality are not aligned. Your changes might not be fully reflected in the database. Have you tried:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>

python manage.py migrate <app_name>
```

You can find more information about how to resolve this error here: [Django ProgrammingError column does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625224/django-programmingerror-column-does-not-exist)

Comment: thanks, what you said it was correct... but the solution that i found was getting the scripts by django and running them on postgres database by my own. I know, nothing pretty the solution, but it helped me.

Thanks for your reply